# i use Loader my project for Flash AC3 but font do not work with Loader why?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, flash-cs6

if i run "janda.swf" , font works but i use Loader and addChild "janda.swf" then font don't work. 
i embeded font my flash library both janda.swf and loader.swf

http://uploads.im/bV3nw.png
http://s1.uploads.im/bV3nw.png

Thanks for your answer now

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem. i embeded the font my library of  "Loader.swf". 
but i use TLFtext in "janda.swf".
the font work in "janda.swf" even if you select outline format Classic(DF3) in Font Embedding panel
if you don't select outline format TLF(DF4) in Font Embedding panel in "Loader.swf", font doesn't work.
Because "janda.swf" is added into "loader.swf" add with addChild.

http://uploads.im/H190u.png - http://s1.uploads.im/H190u.png